# VBA code not working in non English systems

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a VBA program which works perfectly in my computer and other English computers. But it gives a **Runtime 1004** error when the same code is run on French computers. I have changed the primary language of Excel from French to English and yet it shows the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Range M15 to M25 contains percentages from 0 to 100 and N15 to N25 contains percentage from 100 to 0

```
Dim mean1 As String
Dim mean2 As String
If ComboBox1 = "Royal Dutch Shell" Then mean1 = Range("B33")
If ComboBox1 = "Exxon Mobil Corp" Then mean1 = Range("C33")
If ComboBox1 = "PetroChina Co Ltd" Then mean1 = Range("D33")
If ComboBox1 = "British Petroleum" Then mean1 = Range("E33")

If ComboBox2 = "Biogen Inc" Then mean2 = Range("F33")
If ComboBox2 = "Johnson & Johnson" Then mean2 = Range("G33")
If ComboBox2 = "Pfizer Inc" Then mean2 = Range("H33")
If ComboBox2 = "GlaxoSmithKline" Then mean2 = Range("I33")



Sheets("EfficientFrontier").Select

**Runtime Error 1004 starts from here**

   Range("o15").Formula = "=M15 * " & mean1 & " + N15 * " & mean2 & "" 
   Range("o16").Formula = "=M16 * " & mean1 & " + N16 * " & mean2 & ""
   Range("o17").Formula = "=M17 * " & mean1 & " + N17 * " & mean2 & ""
   Range("o18").Formula = "=M18 * " & mean1 & " + N18 * " & mean2 & ""
   Range("o19").Formula = "=M19 * " & mean1 & " + N19 * " & mean2 & ""
   Range("o20").Formula = "=M20 * " & mean1 & " + N20 * " & mean2 & ""
   Range("o21").Formula = "=M21 * " & mean1 & " + N21 * " & mean2 & ""
   Range("o22").Formula = "=M22 * " & mean1 & " + N22 * " & mean2 & ""
   Range("o23").Formula = "=M23 * " & mean1 & " + N23 * " & mean2 & ""
   Range("o24").Formula = "=M24 * " & mean1 & " + N24 * " & mean2 & ""
   Range("o25").Formula = "=M25 * " & mean1 & " + N25 * " & mean2 & ""
```

Comment: Please show us the code that throws the error

Comment: Range("o15").Formula = "=M15 * " & mean1 & " + N15 * " & mean2 & ""   This is the code

Comment: Not just the line of code that the error happens on, but the block of code that it is in would be **very** helpful......

Comment: I am unable to add an image in this comment hence i had to send it that way

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code in the procedure that is causing this error. At the moment we do not have enough information to help you.

Comment: Copy/Paste your code into your question (click edit below the question and copy/paste into there). In the line above and below your code add 3 backticks (`) to make a codeblock format.

Comment: I have added the code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cells of row 33 contains percentage then the value you get is decimal (25% -> 0.25). So when you concatenate this value to build the formula, you have an issue with the decimal separator that is either `.` or `,`. The `,` is a key character in Excel formulas. Thus, it breaks the formula

Try to solve it by casting your variables `mean1` and `mean2` to strings and replace the `,` with `.`. Then use these strings to build your formula

```vb
Dim sMean1, sMean2 as String
sMean1 = Replace(CStr(mean1), ",", ".")
sMean2 = Replace(CStr(mean2), ",", ".")
Range("o15").Formula = "=M15 * " & sMean1 & " + N15 * " & sMean2
```

Other tips :

- End the formula with the concatenation of an empty string `& ""` is useless
- You can use a `For` loop to write the formula instead of `Range("o15")`, `Range("o16")`, ...

```vb
For i = 15 To 20
    ' Column "O" is the 15th column
    Cells(i, 15).Formula = "=M" & i & " * " & sMean1 & " + N" & i & " * " & sMean2
Next i
```

- The `Sheets(...).Select` let the user see the changes the macro does and it slows your program down. You should prefer the `With` syntax

```vb
Dim sMean1, sMean2 as String
sMean1 = Replace(CStr(mean1), ",", ".")
sMean2 = Replace(CStr(mean2), ",", ".")

With Sheets("EfficientFrontier")
    For i = 15 To 20
        ' Column "O" is the 15th column
        ' Note the "." at the beginning of the line below so that the line means Sheets("EfficientFrontier").Cells(i, 15).Formula ...
        .Cells(i, 15).Formula = "=M" & i & " * " & sMean1 & " + N" & i & " * " & sMean2
    Next i
    ' ... other code related to this worksheet
End With
```

Comment: So do i need to create additional variables sMean1 and sMean2 or should i replace Mean1 with sMean1 and Mean2 with sMean2?

Comment: You create new variables. A variable name has no effect on its type

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thank You, you saved me a lot of pain.

Comment: I have a similar problem with another formula **Range("p15").Formula = "=M15^2*" & var1 & "+N15^2*" & var2 & "+2*M15*N15* " & covarval & ""**

Comment: I'm very basic in VBA so I'm not aware with the for loop. But this formula gives an output in column P and again the M15^2 would refer to the percentages.